# Is this the most magnanimous bunch of Protestants/Atheists on the internet?

Tags: discussion

So far two of the most beloved anti-papist sentiments have not been broached, and I'd like to thank ya'll from the bottom of my heart.

https://christianity.stackexchange.com/search?q=galileo

https://christianity.stackexchange.com/search?q=inquisition

Not to jinx the thing, but let's keep it up!

This might be less of a meta question and more of a general question, but I think it only applies to the people who check out stuff here.  What brought about the change of heart is this all just settled stuff that no one cares about anymore?

God love ya'll

Comment: Don't forget the magnanimous atheists too! :)

Comment: Don't forget that this site is only a month old...give it time, the questions will come. And most likely be promptly closed. :P

Comment: I think we have more knowledgeable people *(i.e. hackers)* here than on the average internet forum, and the SE model is excellent at keeping low-quality content out.

Comment: (I just started thinking of good, on-topic, non-argumentative Inquisition questions...)

Answer (score 9):

Most likely because this is Christianity.SE, and not Anti-Catholicism.SE.  There's really not much in the way of **constructive** questions that could be asked on those subjects, IMO.

Comment: I like the emphasis on constructive. Totally true. =]

Answer (score 3):

I guess in my mind, those items were in the past.  They've all been reconciled.

If the Catholic church were still ex-communicating anyone who said that the Earth isn't the center of the universe, there'd probably be more questions.

[It sounds like currently, the issue is just kind of ignored.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo_affair#Modern_Catholic_Church_views)

Answer (score 0):

If I could think of something to say about one of those topics which would actually be a **sensible, answerable question**, believe me I'd ask it. But since anything I'd write about either would be merely a rant, and I'm trying to cut back on ranting in general (and ranting here in particular), I'm avoiding the subjects.